# Galois extension of intersection of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have finite Galois extensions: E/K and E/L.
$$M:=K \cap L$$
I am trying to prove that if the extension E/M is finite then it is also Galois. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124716/separability-over-intersection-of-intermediate-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be the Galois group of $E/K$, and $H$ the one of $E/L$. Let $I$ be the subgroup of the whole automorphism group of $E$ generated by $G$ and $H$. Since $M=K\cap L$, the elements of $G$ and of $H$ are the identity on $M$. It follows that the elements of $I$ are the identity on $M$. This means that the fixed field $E^I$ of $I$ contains $M$. We show that $E^I=M$. Let $x\in E^I$. Then $x\in E^G=K$ and $x\in E^H=L$, i.e., $x\in K\cap L=M$. This proves that $E^I=M$. Since the degree $E/M$ is finite, $I$ is finite. Then one applies the general fact that if $I$ is a finite group of field automorphisms of a field $E$ then the extension $E/E^I$ is a finite Galois extension with Galois group $I$.